# How to remove this text box?

Tags: excel-2010, excel-2013

How do i remove this text box from my excel table ? If i try to write something in that box, it overlap the next cell, but i can write in that box but it has a limited number of character,so if i write more than 11 characters, my box will have the same size, but the text will be pushed.

[image: https://s21.postimg.org/5oupf8hhj/Capture.png] - the box

[image: https://s11.postimg.org/ydq7nrea7/Capture3.png] - more than 11 characters

I don't know how it appeared but i would like to remove it . Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Right-click in the textbox and from the context menu, pick **Delete**